# scanf() reads a minus sign and doesn't put it back

Tags: c, command-line, input, scanf

I am trying to read from the command line either a non negative number or a minus sign and if the input is not one of those the program terminates so I did the following:

```
while((scanf("%d", &n)==1 && n>-1 && (input=1)) || (scanf("%c", &delete)==1 && delete=='-' && (input=2)))
```

`input` is an integer and indicates which was read a number or the minus sign (`input=1` & `input=2` in the loop are intended).

Now, the program works for the numbers, but if I enter a minus sign the first `scanf()` reads it but doesn't put it back apparantly, so the second `scanf()` finds nothing and terminates the program.

However, if I enter `--` (two minus signs) the first `scanf()` reads one and the second `scanf()` reads the other and it all works correctly.

The input from the command line can't be changed, it has to be one minus sign. What is the best way of solving this?

Note that I do know how to use `getchar()` to read the input and then check it but I don't want to do that its a hassle.

Comment: That's some pretty nasty code you've got there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to read entire lines of text into a buffer, and *then* inspect the contents of the buffer, not relying on brittle chains of reading which depend on pushback.

Just use `fgets()` and `sscanf()`.

Comment: hmm, I never actually use these! But after reading about them I think I will be more comfortable with these in the future. I changed my code and now everything works.
Is there a particular situation where you would recommend scanf() as opposed to these?

Comment: @MinaHany Other than for total throw-away code, I don't think so, no. :)