# Problem using fscanf to store double or string values in C

Tags: c, scanf

So I was asked to write a little program in class. I'm learning to code in C and I have problems with this function and the usage of fscanf function, when trying to store a value in different variables depending on its type.

What it is supposed to do is written in comments by my teachers, the rest is my code (I'm not supposed to use any other libraries apart from the included ones):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


/*  A) Tries to read a double from the file and asign its value to the double pointed by num. If it was possible returns 1.
    B) In other case, tries to read a string up to 31 chars and stores its value on the string
    pointed by op, if it was possible returns 2.
    C) In any other case it returns 0 (end of file, etc)*/

int num_or_op(FILE* f, double *num, char *op) {
    
    int aux;
    int read = 0;
    read = fscanf(f, "%lf", num);
    if (read==-1) /*eof*/
    return 0;
    if (read==0){
        aux = fscanf(f, "%31s", op);
        if (aux>0){
            read=2;
        }
    }

return read;
}
```

The problem I'm finding is, following this steps, the program is skipping some characters. I call this function in a while block to store all the data.
If I introduce a file with, for example, 1 2 + 3, it reads 1 and 2, then it's unable to store `+` correctly but instead of doing it in the next fscanf, it just scans the number 3 and adds it to the string pointed by op.
I thought when `fscanf` returned 0, the next call to `fscanf` read the same character that couldn't be read before if the format is correct this time, but apparently it doesn't work that way or I'm probably doing something wrong. I was able to come up with different alternatives, but is there any way to do this in the order that is specified, A,B,C and reading directly from the file with fscanf (not using fgets to get a line for example)? **I was asked to do it with this specific function**.
In case it matters I'm compiling with `gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -o program program.c`
Thanks.

Comment: Related: [scanf() reads a minus sign and doesn't put it back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529530/scanf-reads-a-minus-sign-and-doesnt-put-it-back)

Comment: @WeatherVane the only answer to that question was to just do it with fgets(). I was asked to use fscanf. Also they don't answer what is happening exactly here.

Comment: Can you show us your `main`?

Comment: `if (read==-1) /*eof*/` If you mean `EOF` why don't you use `EOF`? No need to mess around with magic numbers.

Comment: I reproduced your result with MSVC. Using `fscanf` you can extract each item as a string, and apply `sscanf` to that string. When the `double` conversion fails, it's the operator.

Comment: Are you sure it is possible to achieve this with only `fscanf`? I think you need backtracking.

Comment: `char buf[1024]; while (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, f)) { if (sscanf (buf, ...) ... }`

Comment: @Neil not really sure that's why I asked. It seems to be my teachers fault for asking us to do it that impractical way. We are waiting for a response from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right answer was given by @user3386109 in a comment so I add the explanation here to close the question.

After a conversion error with this function, the standard only requires one character of push back, and I am using an implementation that meets the minimum required push back. A good example is the input `-.a`. The parser needs to read three characters to determine that the input isn't a valid `double`. If it only pushes back one character the `-` and `.` are lost. In my case `+` and space are read, and only the space is pushed back. My program is running C version C89/C90.

Comment: Since this is implementation dependent, it would be nice to know what implementation you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int num_or_op( FILE *f, double *num, char *op )
{
  int aux;
  int read = 0;
  read = fscanf( f, "%lf", num );
  if ( read == -1 )
    return 0;
  if ( read == 0 )
  {
    aux = fscanf( f, "%31s", op );
    if ( aux > 0 )
      read = 2;
  }

  return read;
}

int main( void )
{
  char op[32] = {0};
  double d = 0.0;

  int r;

  do
  {
    r = num_or_op( stdin, &d, op );
    printf( "num_or_op returned %d", r );
    if ( r == 1 )
      printf( ": d = %f", d );
    else if ( r == 2 )
      printf( ": op = %s", op );
    putchar ('\n' );
  } while ( r != 0 );
 
  return 0;
}
```

Using `1 2 + 3` as input:

```
$ echo 1 2 + 3 | ./num_or_op
num_or_op returned 1: d = 1.000000
num_or_op returned 1: d = 2.000000
num_or_op returned 2: op = +
num_or_op returned 1: d = 3.000000
num_or_op returned 0
```

With slightly more obnoxious input:

```
$ echo 1 2 + 3 4 - foo 5 / 6 | ./num_or_op
num_or_op returned 1: d = 1.000000
num_or_op returned 1: d = 2.000000
num_or_op returned 2: op = +
num_or_op returned 1: d = 3.000000
num_or_op returned 1: d = 4.000000
num_or_op returned 2: op = -
num_or_op returned 2: op = foo
num_or_op returned 1: d = 5.000000
num_or_op returned 2: op = /
num_or_op returned 1: d = 6.000000
num_or_op returned 0
```

Maybe your problem is in the calling code?

Having said that, I do have some stylistic issues with your code.  Things like using `-1` instead of `EOF`, or needing that second `aux` variable, etc.  Turns out that function can be a lot cleaner:

```
int num_or_op( FILE *f, double *num, char *op )
{
  int read = 0;

  if ( fscanf( f, "%lf", num ) == 1 )
    read = 1;
  else if ( fscanf( f, "%31s", op ) == 1 )
    read = 2;

  return read;
}
```

Comment: The code works for you because you're using an implementation that pushes back multiple characters after a conversion failure. The standard only requires one character of push back, and OP seems to be using an implementation that meets the minimum required push back. A good example is the input `-.a`. The parser needs to read three characters to determine that the input isn't a valid `double`. If it only pushes back one character the `-` and `.` are lost. In OP's case `+` and space are read, and only the space is pushed back.